# Installing MongoExpress with npm

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have hit this error when running 'npm install ­-g mongo­express' on windows 10.

```
C:\>npm install ­g mongo­express
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\­g
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\mongo­express
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Daniel\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "­g" "mongo­express"
npm ERR! node v4.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.3
npm ERR! path C:\­g
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\­g'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log
```

The contents of the 'C:\npm-debug.log' are:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Daniel\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '­g',
1 verbose cli   'mongo­express' ]
2 info using npm@3.3.3
3 info using node@v4.0.0
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData ­g
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData mongo­express
9 silly fetchOtherPackageData ­g
10 silly cache add args [ '­g', null ]
11 verbose cache add spec ­g
12 silly fetchOtherPackageData mongo­express
13 silly cache add args [ 'mongo­express', null ]
14 verbose cache add spec mongo­express
15 silly cache add parsed spec Result {
15 silly cache add   raw: '­g',
15 silly cache add   scope: null,
15 silly cache add   name: null,
15 silly cache add   rawSpec: '­g',
15 silly cache add   spec: 'C:\\­g',
15 silly cache add   type: 'local' }
16 silly cache add parsed spec Result {
16 silly cache add   raw: 'mongo­express',
16 silly cache add   scope: null,
16 silly cache add   name: null,
16 silly cache add   rawSpec: 'mongo­express',
16 silly cache add   spec: 'C:\\mongo­express',
16 silly cache add   type: 'local' }
17 error addLocal Could not install C:\­g
18 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\­g'
18 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Error (native)
18 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for ­g { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\­g'] errno: -4058, code: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'open', path: 'C:\\­g' }
19 error addLocal Could not install C:\mongo­express
20 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\mongo­express'
20 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Error (native)
20 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for mongo­express { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\mongo­express']
20 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: -4058,
20 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'ENOENT',
20 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'open',
20 silly fetchPackageMetaData   path: 'C:\\mongo­express' }
21 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
22 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
23 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
24 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
25 silly install printInstalled
26 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\­g'
26 verbose stack     at Error (native)
27 verbose cwd C:\
28 error Windows_NT 10.0.10240
29 error argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Daniel\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "­g" "mongo­express"
30 error node v4.0.0
31 error npm  v3.3.3
32 error path C:\­g
33 error code ENOENT
34 error errno -4058
35 error syscall open
36 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\­g'
36 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
36 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
37 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
```

It appears node is taking the -g parameter as a file name to install express into? My understanding was that this makes express globally accessible. With variations to this command I run into similar problems. 
I have since also ran into this problem attempting to install other modules.

Link to mongo-express's node install site: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mongodb

Could anyone give me a hand?

Comment: is it not `npm install -g mongoexpress`? with `-g`?

Comment: Sorry that is what I tried. When I copied or pasted the command, something has taken out the - symbol. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
npm install -g mongoexpress
```

The g is a command line flag. The command you're running is saying "install module g and module mongoexpress" instead of "install mongoexpress globally".